# New Ubunu 16.04.3 installation extremely slow

Tags: partitioning

I noticed there are some posts on Ubuntu being slow, but none of the solutions apply here.

My previous configuration with Ubuntu used several partitions, and it was lightning fast. I then put all my user files in a separate partition

When I rebuilt the installation, I let Ubuntu decide on partitions, using the default user locations. It is now like glue... on exactly the same box.

BUT:
I did stop Tracker by:

```
tracker daemon -t
```

which improved the speed tremendously.

Any other suggestions, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can find what is slowing down your machine using `top` or `htop` if the problem is CPU related and using `iotop` to find problems related to high disk usage.

You have probably to install `htop` and `iotop` before using them.

```
sudo apt install htop iotop
```

`iotop` must be run using `sudo iotop`.